# Blackberry publish in facebook

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I'm developing an application for Blackberry and i need to know what is the best solution in order to post in the user's wall on Facebook.

Thanks

Edited: I need to post in user's wall

Comment: verify this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284182/blackberry-facebook-graph-api-like-the-post-of-users/7284550#7284550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should check Facebook BlackBerry SDK:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best, but you could simple invoke facebook sharelink in BrowserField

```
    String FACEBOOK_SHARE_URL = "http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php";
    String FACEBOOK_URL_PARAM = "u";
    String FACEBOOK_TITLE_PARAM = "t";

    String shareLink = "http://www.links.com/link123";
    String title= "Title";

    String url = FACEBOOK_SHARE_URL + "?" + FACEBOOK_URL_PARAM + "=" +
                  shareLink + "&" + FACEBOOK_TITLE_PARAM + "=" + appName;

     BrowserField browser = new BrowserField();
     add(browser);
     browser.requestContent(url + ";deviceside=true");
```