# Blackberry facebook Graph API. "Like" the post of users

Tags: facebook, post, blackberry, facebook-like

I am developing blackberry application that use the Facebook functionality. I do every thing using the Graph API of facebook for blackberry. But my problem is that i m not able to "like" or "comment" on any post or photo.

Can you please give the source code or help example on how to like the post of user.

I read the ["Post - Facebook Developers"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) but i m not getting what it actually saying or how to achieve this functionality.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know about graph api.but if it possible download  this api http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/
and you can do everything here easily.if you need any help ask me

Comment: I download and try using same SDK. I do everything but i dont know how to "like" facebook post. And really very thanks for help.

Thank you so muck. Can you provide more help on that?

Answer (score 2):

you just add that jar file to your application
next just write following code

```
     ApplicationSettings sett=new ApplicationSettings("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html", "facebooke  id", "secret key", Permissions.ALL_PERMISSIONS);    
     facebook=Facebook.getInstance(sett);
    user = facebook.getCurrentUser();
    String result=user.publishPost(String pMessage, String pLink, String pPictureurl, String pName, String pCaption, String pDescription, String pSource);
```

if result value not null thaen your post successfull

Comment: You are right. I have done same as above. But my Question is different. My question is "Suppose i you publishPost as above. Now I am able to get that post using Post object but the actual problem is that How i can "like" the Post, OR how can i "comment" on that Post".
That is my problem. If Are you getting my question, please i request you to provide sample code as you provide" Not complete example i need just core part. Thanks for giving your valuable time.